# Google Apps Script to Truncate Text with TimeDrivenTigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a script that limits text strings in a google sheets.  The script that I am using works when I manually add text to the sheet, but when I import data using Zapier, the script does not run.

I was trying to set up a Time Driven Trigger to run the script every hour, but have not had success.

This is what I'm using:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every 1 hours.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
  .timeBased()
  .everyHours(1)
  .create();

  function MyFunction(e) {
    var limit = 4;
    if(e.value.length > limit) {
      e.range.setValue(e.value.substring(0, limit));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How were you calling `MyFunction` before trying to set up the Time Driven Trigger?

Comment: I was using 'onEdit' to trigger the text reduction.

Answer (score 0):

You were initially calling `MyFunction` with an `onEdit()` trigger, which passes an [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to the function. This is the parameter `e` that you get the value of. A time-driven trigger doesn't pass in any arguments, so you will have to re-write `MyFunction` a little, to find the range you're interested in "from scratch."

Also, your trigger calls `myFunction` (lowercase), while the function is defined as `MyFunction` (uppercase), which could be an issue.